# Conditional probability distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $(X,Y)$ have probability density function

$ f(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \frac{1}{2}y^2e^{-x}, \quad 0 < x < y < \infty  \\ 0,  \quad \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right. $

Then $  P(Y<1 | X=3)$ equals

I know that $  P(Y<1 | X=3)$ equals  $  \frac{ f_{xy}(Y<1 \cap X=3)}{f_x(X=3)}$

But the thing is for a continuous probability distribution $ P(X=a) =0$ . So the above Probability becomes invalid right?

So how do we solve this question?

Comment: You should denote the above function by $f_{XY}(x,y)$ (and there is probably a missing $y$ in the $e$). Then $f_{Y\vert X=3}=\tfrac{f_{XY}(3,y)}{f_X(3)}$ and this is a the conditional pdf with which you can solve the question.

Comment: Your definition of the joint density appears to contain typographical errors.  Please correct it.

Comment: To correct it, you can click on the light-grey "edit" just below your question.

Comment: Your $f(x,y)$ seems not even normalizable (Its integral over the $(x,y)$ space is infinity)... So it is not really a "probablity density function...".  If it is $f(x,y)$ is normalized, even though $P(X=3)=0$, you also have $P(Y<1|X=3)=0$. Thus the conditional probablity is still meaningful, defined as $\int_{-\infty}^1 f(x=3,y) dy / \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x=3,y) dy$

Comment: As @MoonKnight said, the question is ill-posed for multiple reasons. It must have be written incorrectly. You should consult your instructor or, if it is from a text, a list of errata.